# Which weighted directed hypergraphs have incidence matrix of full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraphs

what are the necessary conditions for a weighted directed hypergraph to have an incidence matrix of full rank?

This question is a generalization of this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5553/which-graphs-have-incidence-matrices-of-full-rank